# Rails 5.0.3 Real Favicon Generator produces local host error: ActionView::MissingTemplate in Websites#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, ruby-on-rails-5, favicon

I am fairly new to Rails using realfavicongenerator.net to produce favicons for my Rails 5.0.3 application on my Windows machine. realfavicongenerator.net seems like the way to go - producing many favicons instead of the one-at-a-time approach.

I appear to have generated the favicons correctly: My project folder shows a "Your generated favicon_files" folder at the same level as the "app" folder. It also shows a "Your generated favicons.html" file.

I had originally placed the favicon.json file under the project `folder/config`, but changed it to `app/assets/config/favicon.json` after I realized my mistake. (realfavicongenerator.net doesn't specify which config folder to use.)

Now I am getting an error:

```
localhost:3000: "ActionView::MissingTemplate in Websites#index."
```

The error on my rails server:

```
>ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial application/_favicon with >>>{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Sites/railsbridge/metasara/app/views"
):
    4:     <title>MetaSara</title>
    5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    6:
    7:     <%= render 'application/favicon' %>
    8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    9:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   10:   </head>
```

Note that I have attempted to place underscores in front of several files to designate them as partials. I have not found a working combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, when talking about a Rails application, `config`, `app`, etc... refer to the root of your project. So if you are working in `/home/me/my_super_rails_app`, the `config` directory is actually `/home/me/my_super_rails_app/config`, while `app/assets` actually means `/home/me/my_super_rails_app/app/assets`.

`favicon.json` should be in `config` (not in `app/assets/config`).

The favicon partial should be in `app/views/application`. In other words, `app/views/application/_favicon.html.erb` should exists.

Comment: @phillipe_b Thanks for the response! I do not have a app/views/application directory. I will try #realfavicongenerator again keeping your directory structure in mind.

Comment: @phillipe_b Thanks for the directory help. I now know that the problem is not in my app structure. I still don't have favicons, just an empty favicon folder under  ```app/assets/images```. I am getting a ```certificate verify failed``` notice that I think is the next problem to investigate.

Comment: I solved the certificate error and my favicons loaded into my favicon folder! After fixing another problem, my website displays its favicon. See http://metasara.herokuapp.com/ Too bad I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer. Thanks for your help!